# PHP: Поиск соответствия выражению с помощью in_array, если в массиве слово заканчивается на *

Tags: php

Дан некоторый массив с правами пользователя (Для примера):

```
$perms = array("group_1_edit","group_2_delete", "group_3*");
```

На странице задана функция, которая проверяет наличие доступа по флагу

```
function check_perm($req_flag){
    global $perms;
    if(in_array($req_flag, $perms)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

На странице для проверки просто if с функцией

```
<?php if(check_perm(group_3_edit)){?>
    Доступ разрешен
<?php } ?>
```

Каким образом осуществить проверку, что если у пользователя имеется флаг group_x* (x некоторое значение), то предоставляем доступ ко всем флагам, которые начинаются с group_x (group_x_любое_продолжение)?

Comment: для поиска не точных соответствий обычно пользуются регулярными выражениями.

Comment: или регулярные выражения или примерно такой алгоритм: вырезаете последний символ (предварительно не забудьте trim), если это звёздочка, то от вашего значения отрезаете последний символ и начинаете сравнивать его с отрезанными столькими же первыми символами от $reg_flag.

Comment: у вас там кстати кавычек не хватает при вызове, нотис в логи пишется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот вам для размышлений. сначала проверить обычное вхождение. потом отобрать те подстроки, где есть `*`. звездочку заменить на `.*` и использовать это как шаблон регулярки.

```
function check_perm2($req){
    global $perms;

    if(in_array($req, $perms)) return true;

    $regs = array_filter(array_map(function($v){
                    if(mb_strpos($v, '*') === false) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return str_replace('\*', '.*', preg_quote($v));
                }, $perms));


    foreach($regs as $r){
        if(preg_match("/^{$r}$/", $req)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

зы: странновато видеть процедурное программирование, когда логичным было бы видеть записи вида `if($user->has('group_1_delete'))` или `$user->permissions->check('group_3_edit')` и так далее. Глобальные массивы прав и т.п. в данном вопросе вряд ли можно назвать хорошими практиками.

Comment: Спасибо за материал для раздумий и вариант решения. Ну в конечном варианте функция всё равно будет в классе юзера, так что к такому виду и стремлюсь в записях.

Answer (score 1):

> *Каким образом осуществить проверку, что если у пользователя имеется флаг group_x* (x некоторое значение), то предоставляем доступ ко всем флагам, которые начинаются с group_x (group_x_любое_продолжение)?*

Переписать функцию таким образом, чтобы она принимала два параметра - искомое значение *(флаг)*, и собственно массив значений для поиска.

Далее элементы массива `$perms` подставлять в шаблон регулярных выражений, предварительно заменив символ `*` на последовательность символов `.*`. А значение переменной `$req_flag` использовать как строку для поиска соответствий *(обновлённый ответ)*:

---

```
$perms = ['group_1_edit', 'group_2_delete', 'group_3*'];
$req_flag = 'group_3_edit';

if (check_perm($req_flag, $perms)) {
    echo 'Доступ разрешен';
}


function check_perm($flag, $perms) {
    return array_filter($perms, function($pcre) use($flag) {
        return preg_match('~'. strtr($pcre, '*', '.*') .'~', $flag);
    });
}
```

Comment: `\w` включает `\d`. но ответ я все равно не понял оО вопрос вроде про то что в массиве есть разрешение `group_3*` и при проверке  `group_3_qwe` или `group_3_asd` должно возвращать `true`.

Comment: @teran да, `\w` включает цифры, но использование записи `group_\w+` будет совпадать и с `group_text`, а по условию задачи, там должна быть цифра :)

Comment: а, пардоньте, туплю

Comment: @teran а насчёт `group_3_qwe` и `group_3_asd` - если он их добавит в массив, то оно совпадёт. Вообще, тут можно убрать in_array() и искать по массиву регуляркой, принимая динамический pcre-шаблон.

Comment: дак в этом и суть, что он в массив хочет добавить `group_3*`, а не каждую отдельно, а проверять их. они и с обычным `in_array` совпадут, если так добавить, тут и делать нечего тогда.

Comment: Регулярку надо экранировать (`preg_quote`) и дополнить утверждениями `^` и `$` (начало и конец строки). `.*` неудачный выбор, так как, например, `group_3*` совпадёт с `group_31_annihilation`, хотя не должен бы.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин `preg_quote` можно добавить, если не известно, какие символы будут в строке. А вот зачем привязываться к позициям в одной единственной строке _(^ и $)_ - остаётся загадкой. И на счёт совпадений с `group_31_annihilation` - ну дак это автру и нужно, чтобы совпадало начиная с group_3(и отсюда любые соответствия). Перечитайте ещё раз вопрос, и не отнимайте моё время - добавьте ваш ответ.